# problems to style iframe content

Tags: jquery, iframe

I try a long time to style this simple soundcloud player example with jquery.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="player" width="300px" height="50px" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F60778614&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;color=ff7733&amp;show_bpm=true"></iframe>
<script>
$('#player').contents().find('body').hide();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(I only want to change the bg color in .singleTrack and #widget but nothing work)
could somebody help me

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the iframe content.

If you want to make some changes you have to edit iframe's CSS directly (if you can access it).

Comment: No I dont have access to the soundcloud servers :)

Comment: That's what I thought ;-) In that case you have to take what they give.

Comment: is it possibe to delete the original css file and load my own? via jquery

Comment: Nope, you CAN'T change the content of the `iframe`, it would be a huge security threat.